# Having another programmer take over an existing project

Tags: asp.net

This question is not coming from a programmer. (obviously)  I currently have a programmer making a website for me and I am realizing that he isn't going to completely work out.

He has already done quite a bit of work and the site is almost there but I need someone who is better to take it the rest of way. The site has been done in asp.net and I am wondering how hard it would be for a more experienced programmer to take over and finish the work he has already done?

In general, is it hard for an asp.net programmer to come in towards the end of a project and fix what needs to be fixed?

There is five different pages on the site with two overlays for a signup and sign in. (Five pages with many different versions) There is a database and client-side scripting. AJAX was also used.  It's a site somewhat similar to SO only not quite as complex and about something completly different.  I would say think of something that falls somewhere between Stackoverflow and Craig's List. Thats all I can say now as I don't know the technical words.

Comment: If you could provide a little more information on the scope of the project it would help us. Do you know the number of files / pages in the project? Lines of code? Is there a database? How many tables? Were any 3rd party components used? Was client-side scripting used? Was AJAX used? How long did it take to write? If you don't know the answers, can you ask someone that does?

Comment: I know some of those answers but let me find out the rest and get back to you.  Thanks Mark.

Comment: Why do you think he won't work out?  Do you know the average quality of his code?

Comment: @nick2653 After seeing your update: You say there are 5 pages with different versions. Are there different source files for each version or do they share the same code? How many users/topics/posts do you expect? Has the existing codebase been performance tested at all? If the design needs to be changed for performance reasons, this could be a big job.

Comment: The pages share the same code. As for users, at first I am expecting about what some of the stackexchange sites have.  The existing codebase has not been tested yet.  I'm realizing that this is a hard question to answer without seeing the site first hand.  I guess I need to find a good programmer, let the person take a look, and then see what he/she thinks about trying to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good idea will be to have them work together,for say, a week or two. This will help the new programmer get some much needed training about your current system.

Comment: Yes, I hope this is the best way to handover an exisiting program to new programmer!

Answer (score 16):

You'll probably find that the new programmer will want to rewrite most of the code from scratch. If you are on a tight deadline or tight budget and can't accept a complete rewrite then you will need to hire someone that is not just good at writing good code, but good at reading, refactoring and improving bad code. It is two completely different skillsets and the second is much rarer. Depending on the quality of the existing code (and I'm assuming here that it is not good), your new programmer may end up rewriting much of the existing codebase just to understand what is going on.

Comment: Its not just a more rare talent, it is a more *expensive* talent as well.

Comment: +1... I was about to say the same thing. If you're not rich, and have a limited amount of time, you depend on your old programmer somewhat. First try to check out whether there isn't some way you can make it work out with him somehow. Changing programmers is going to hurt. To tell how badly exactly, somebody will have to take a look at your code.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how good the previous programmer was and on the complexity of the project. It might be anything between trivial (well commented source, some high-level docs, unit tests, modular or simple project), to "this crap needs a complete rewrite" (no docs, custom "let's try this" solutions, etc.). If you're not a developer it might be really hard to tell. And other people won't be able to answer without more details.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no asp.net expert, but I suspect the ease with which the replacement will be able to finish the project will depend mostly on just how bad a job the first programmer actaully did. Bad code is painful to fix in any language. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find that although the site is almost complete, the successor will have to spend more time than anticipated when performing alterations, as this person will have the mental model of the software that the current developer has.  Hence the need to next developer to "re-write" the code base.

If you can, you'll want to ensure that the code base that you have built is maintainable.  That is, the solution is built in such a way that it can support alterations easily.  As Mark Byers suggested, you'll want to get someone who can not only program but can also re-work your existing code with the goal being that someone else will inevitably implement future changes. If the software is something that you need to keep working for an extended period you'll want to make the investment in making sure that it new functionality can be added easily.

Answer (score 1):

Remember this experience described at [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Maybe-I-Needing-Later.aspx).  Take appropriate precautions.

Comment: I took the burden to read this, it was great I bookedmarked this one tkx

Answer (score 0):

Generally if the site is set up in some sort of standard fashion then another programmer should be able to pick it up easily.  if the existing programmer did things to obscure the code then it will be hard for another programmer to pick it up.  Basically the question is how readable is the code?

Answer (score 0):

If the current programmer is unwilling to communicate the true status of the project in a professional, non-technical manner, then give him an ultimatum - your way or the highway. Odds are he will be more forthcoming if he knows you mean business. Make sure you have a copy of the latest code before broaching the subject.

It sounds like you are going to end up hiring someone else anyway, especially if you're asking these kinds of questions at this stage, so you might as well go for broke.

As Mark Byers said, it takes a seasoned developer to take someone else's code and resist the urge to "pretty it up" in order to bring the project to a working conclusion!